# Рефакторинг кода?

Tags: php, инспекция-кода

Как можно сократить и привести в порядок код?

```
<form method="post" action="date_filter.php">

     <select name="dateFirst">

     <?php
     while($row_res = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
     ?>

     <option value="<?php echo $row_res['date']; ?>"><?php echo $row_res['date']; ?></option>

     <?php } ?>

     </select>

     <select name="dateLast">
     <?php
     while($row_res2 = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
     ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row_res2['date']; ?>"><?php echo $row_res2['date']; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Выбрать">
</form>
```

Comment: и что так уж сильно не нравится?

Comment: прочитайте вывод бд в массив и отдайте его сюда

Comment: Ваш вариант далеко не самый плохой. Единственно, что когда идет такая плотная набивка вывода вставками из `<?php echo`, то имеет смысл все кодом выводить, а не устраивать лоскутное одеяло

Comment: используйте шаблонизаторы, отделяйте логику от представления, и будет вам счастие

Comment: @teran а вот react не согласился бы xD

Answer (score 2):

> Как можно сократить и привести в порядок код?

Можно написать хэлпер для использование в видах, чтобы улучшить читабельность и уменьшить дублирование кода:

```
<form method="post" action="date_filter.php">
    <select name="dateFirst">
        <?php
            print getOptions($source, [
             'value' => 'date',
             'text'  => 'date'
            ]);
        ?>
    </select>
    <select name="dateLast">
        <?php
            print getOptions($source, [
             'value' => 'date',
             'text'  => 'date'
            ]);
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Выбрать">
</form>
```

---

```
<?php

function getOptions(array $source, array $keys)
{
    $options = ""
    for ($i = 0, $len = count($source); $i < $len; ++$i)
    {
        $options .= sprintf('<option value="%s">%s</option>',
            htmlspecialchars($source[$keys['value']]),
            htmlspecialchars($source[$keys['text']], ENT_NOQUOTES)
        );
    }

    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Код хелпера хорошо бы добавить

Comment: Добавил, приблизительно такой код.

Comment: отдельный респект за `sprintf` и `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: после первого htmlspecialchars() запятую пропустил. Напомните чем обусловлен флаг ENT_NOQUOTES -?

Comment: Верно, здесь он не нужен.
Я его использовал для плагина select2.

Comment: @rjhdby
Cпасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно и так в вашем случае.
Но лучше, конечно же, передавать массив вторым аргументом.

```
<form method="post" action="date_filter.php">

     <?php echo createSelect('dateFirst', $res) ?>
     <?php echo createSelect('dateLast', $res2) ?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Выбрать">
</form>

<?php

function createSelect ($name, $res) {
    $html = '<select name="' . $name .'">';
    while($row_res = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        $html .= "\t<option value=\"" . $row_res['date'] .'">' . $row_res['date'] . "</option>\n";
    }
    $html .= '</select>';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: а `\t` заназачем?

Comment: Робит, но не до конца. dateFirst выводит как положено, а вот dateLast не выводит вообще. Изменил у dateLast на $res вместо $res2, появилась форма и кнопка, но содержимое у dateLast пустое.

Comment: @rjhdby отделение option от select))

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю такой вариант:

```
<form method="post" action="date_filter.php">
     <select name="dateFirst">

     <?php
       while ($row_res = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo '<option value="', $row_res['date'], '">', $row_res['date'], '</option>';
       }
     ?>

     </select>
     <select name="dateLast">

     <?php
       while ($row_res2 = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo '<option value="', $row_res2['date'], '">', $row_res2['date'], '</option>';
       }
     ?>

     </select>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Выбрать">
</form>
```

Конструкцию echo хорошо использовать при выводе коротких данных, причём вместо оператора присваивания нужно указывать значения через запятую, как аргументы. Это понижает вычислительные затраты.

Comment: И сильно понижает?

Comment: @rjhdby в некоторых случаях разница по времени выполнения составляет 60% в пользу вывода через запятую. Это объясняется тем, что при перечислении через запятую значения выводятся сразу по их порядку, а при использовании точки происходит операция присваивания и после готовая строка выводится. Подробные результаты исследования представлены там: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/

Comment: Статья 2007 года, PHP 5.2 в лучшем случае, `Joining three 100 characters strings four million times`, 2.08с vs 3.52с,  вам самому не смешно?

Comment: Нет, это факт. Протестировал на PHP7. Точки воспроизводятся за 4.0 секунд, запятые за 3.8 при 25.000.000 повторов . Код: http://codepad.org/wPAIhUWS  . Но соглашусь только с тем, что экономия слишком мала для того, чтобы столь усердно доказывать её существование. Этот совет я часто встречал в гайдах по оптимизации.

Comment: Советы по оптимизации такие советы... Оптимизации такого рода хороши на задачах типа программирования микроконтроллеров, где идет борьба за каждый такт и байт (это не про PHP, как вы понимаете). В более менее реальных задачах, для которых используется PHP, на порядки более весомое значение принимают унификация, качество кода и удобство его сопровождения, нежели хитрые лайфхаки на 0.2 секунды выигранные на 25 миллионах(!) операциях вывода через `echo`(!!!). У запятой в `echo` есть гораздо более весомое преимущество, хотя и не особо часто нужное, перед конкатенацией, но о нем ни слова не сказали

Comment: @Eddir, эм, серьезно? выиграли 2 десятых за 25КК операций? В 99% реальных задач нет таких нагрузок, чтобы париться об оптимизации, тем более такой